# Get user profile photo for each message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I need to display each user's unique photo in a chat room. Laravel Jetstream

Getting user message

```
 {{ message.message}}
```

Initially I had, but realized it only gets the photo for the current logged in user.

```
:src="$page.props.user.profile_photo_url
```

I need to define a has one relationship and call something like:

Get user id which lines up with the user account

```
 {{ message.user_id}}
```

Then get the profile photo location from user table column but I can't seem to get it working

```
 {{ user->where('id','=',message.user_id)->value(photo_location) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of your code is incorrect, but I don't think it needs to be fixed because what you did is a very bad practice when it comes to querying data.

Let's say you display 50 message in a page. In this case, you have to make 50 extra queries to fetch user fotos. This will kill your app's performance. That's why you need to attach user's data to the messages. All you need is the following addition to the controller.

```php
$messages = Message::with('user')->...->get();
```

If users table has a foreign key to profile photo, your query should be:

```
$messages = Message::with('user.relation_name')->...->get();
```

In the blade, you will have all user's data you need, and use it like

```php
{{ message->user->profile_photo_url }}
```

To make this work, you will need one-to-many relationship between User and Message models, and I assume you have it already. If you don't check the docs. It's quite easy.

************************/EDIT*/*************

**Relationships**

Chat Message Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ChatRoom','id','user_id');
}
```

Message Controller

```
    $messages= ChatMessage::where('chat_room_id','=',$roomId)
    ->with('user')
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->get();
```

Then in the vue trying to test and get user id for the message, doesn't work

```
{{ message.user.id }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't seem to get the relationship working. Do I need to pass it as a prop too? to the message item?

Comment: It's part of message object. So you don't need to pass it anywhere.

Comment: I've added code of my model/controller cant seem to get it right.

Comment: Sorted it out used wrong model